# How to approximate $\int \frac{1}{1+Cx^2}H_n^2dm$ where $H_n$ Hermite polynomial $m$ Gaussian measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

How to give an approximate value of $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+Cx^2}H_n^2dm$$ where $H_n$ probabilistic Hermite polynomial $m$ Gaussian measure $C>0$

Comment: Is it $dm$ or $dx$ ?

Comment: $dm$ Gaussian measure